# Error even after setting environment variable ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

Tags: android-studio

Even after setting the environment variable in .bashrc ,I am getting 
**Emulator: PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT**
I have written below lines to set set environment variable in .bashrc

**export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk

export PATH=$PATH:'/home/nikki/Android/Sdk/platform-tools':'/home/nikki/Android/Sdk/tools'

export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Android/Sdk**

echo $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is also returning the correct path.What else can be done?
I am using ubuntu